# PageFactory and Appium's IOSElements are not compatible - alternative solution?

Tags: java, webdriver, appium, pageobjects

IOSElements contain the .setValue() method, which types much faster than sendKeys(). However, if I set my elements (using @FindBy annotations) to IOSElement rather than WebElement, PageFactory will return an error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement field screens.LoginScreen.signInEmail to org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$62bef779

Additionally, I cannot cast WebElements to IOSElements, as that will return an error from the JVM as well (cannot cast).

Is there a way to initialize IOSElements using the PageFactory design? My sample code is as follows:

```
public class LoginScreen {

private WebDriver driver;

@FindBy(className = "UIATextField")
public IOSElement signInEmail;

@FindBy(className = "UIASecureTextField")
public IOSElement signInPassword;

@FindBy(id = "Log in")
public IOSElement loginButton;

@FindBy(id = "Forgot your password?")
public IOSElement forgotPasswordButton;

public LoginScreen(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
}

public SomeOtherObject login(String email, String password) {
    signInEmail.setValue(email);
    signInPassword.setValue(password);
    loginButton.click();
    return new SomeOtherObject(driver);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my problem was that I was using a remote instance of WebDriver, like so:

```
this.driver = new WebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

However, I can get an instance of IOSDriver with an identical set up:

```
this.driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

This accepts IOSElements when passed to PageFactory.initElements(); - No errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `@iOSFindBy` annotation for locators of `WebElement` type.
You can find some example on the Appium [github page](https://github.com/appium/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/java/junit/src/test/java/com/saucelabs/appium/page_object/android/ApiDemosListViewScreenSimple.java).

Another thing that I'm thinking of for you example, is to try casting to `MobileElement` instead of `WebElement`.

EDIT:

I've tried this now and I'm able to use `@iOSFindBy`annotation along with `IOSElement` locators type.
I've set up a simple class, using in my Maven `pom.xml` the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, the test class, as follows:

```
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.iOSFindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class ATestClass {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @iOSFindBy(className = "classname")
    public IOSElement testing;

    public ATestClass(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    public void ATestMethod()
    {
        testing.click();
    }
}
```

Note: Same thing goes when `MobileElement` locators type, so in case you're still seeing any errors, check whatever dependencies you're having as most likely those are the ones that are causing your errors.

Comment: Unforunately, using iOSFindBy still leaves me with the problem that I can only initialize WebElements. I cannot cast them to MobileElement or to iOSElement.

Comment: Updated my answer with example code. Please check and maybe try it for yourself in a brand new project, just to determine whether your issue is coming from libraries or from some other part in your original project.

Comment: consider using AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver instead of Webdriver